# Cannot resize Ubuntu disk using wubi-resize (Installed from Wubi)

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, wubi

I'd like to expand my disk space in Ubuntu. Right now, it has 30 GB space which is the maximum allowable installation size in Wubi.

I wanted to extend it to 50 GB so I've done a live resizing according to this [website](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeWubiDisk)

I've already executed the first command which is:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero bs=1MiB of=/host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk conv=notrunc oflag=append count=20480
```

After 10 minutes I've executed the 2nd command:

```
sudo losetup -c /dev/loop0/
```

But it outputs an error:

```
loop: can't set capacity on device /dev/loop0/: Not a directory
```

Is there anything I can do to work this around?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it.

It seems I've put it an extra slash at the code:

```
sudo losetup -c /dev/loop0/
```

Whereas it should it be:

```
sudo losetup -c /dev/loop0
```

I've successfully expanded my partitions with no problems.